Quiescense search problems
Im currently working on a chess engine in python using the chess library. I have attempted to implement a quiescense search by using the pseudocode from the chess programming wiki, but once I run the code on a test position, the search takes a really long time (like 10-20 minutes).
I tried to make it print the moves that it was searching during the quiescense search, and it just prints a constant stream of many moves.
Here's my code:
    def search_all_captures(self, alpha, beta):

        evaluation = self.evaluate()
        if evaluation >= beta:
            return beta
        alpha = max(alpha, evaluation)

        moves = [capture for capture in self.board.generate_legal_captures()]

        move_dict = {}


        # Ordering moves
        for move in moves:
            guess = 0
            move_piece = self.board.piece_at(move.from_square)
            captured_piece = self.board.piece_at(move.to_square)

            if captured_piece:
                guess += 10 * vals_dict[captured_piece.piece_type] - vals_dict[move_piece.piece_type]

            if move.promotion:
                guess += vals_dict[move.promotion]

            if self.board.attackers(1 - self.color, move.to_square):
                for attacker in self.board.attackers(1 - self.color, move.to_square):
                    piece = self.board.piece_at(attacker).piece_type
                    guess -= vals_dict[piece]

            move_dict[move] = guess

        moves.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda move: move_dict[move])

        for move in moves:
            print(move)
            self.board.push(move)
            evaluation = -self.search_all_captures(-beta, -alpha)
            self.board.pop()

            if evaluation >= beta:
                return beta

            alpha = max(alpha, evaluation)

        return alpha

Here is the FEN string for the position: r3k2r/p1ppqpb1/bn2pnp1/3PN3/1p2P3/2N2Q1p/PPPBBPPP/R3K2R w - - 0 1

Quiescence search usually only considers captures that are advantageous to the player on the move and exhausts quickly. Otherwise you will end up considering zillions of ways of sacrificing high mobility pieces like the queen to capture a humble pawn. Sometimes quiescence gets it wrong and the winning move involves losing the queen. This link on SOMA  might help. Suggest  you use a much simpler position where you can work it out by hand.

I was able to make it a lot better by adding a depth limit, but it is still taking around 6 seconds.

How long does your code take for a N-ply deep search from this position N = 1,2,3,4,5 without the quiescence search (ie raw evaluation function)? Do you have killer move and null move heuristics implimented?

1 ply: 0.003 seconds, 2 ply: 0.03 seconds, 3 ply: 0.54 seconds, 4 ply: 2.65 seconds, 5 ply: 37.5 seconds. I have not implemented killer moves yet.

I'll try to answer the basics by hand calculation but I haven't done this stuff seriously for a long while and heuristics do change. Your basic position is:

Quiescence will only consider moves where the player to move can gain material advantage or at least not lose any (so that all neutral swapoffs get processed). Quiescence search usually doesn't consider high value piece sacrifices - indeed it exists to prevent engines from throwing their pieces away just to delay an inevitable checkmate by one more move.
I think it will be sufficient to make small change to your code so that it only explores recursive captures for the lines where there was a net material gain for the player on the move IOW when guess >= 0
if move_dict[move] >= 0 :
   evaluation = -self.search_all_captures(-beta, -alpha)

I can't spot where it recognises K in check which is also a non-quiescent state.
Whites immediate capture moves under consideration are with net positive or zero material gain:
1a. BXB (Ba6 is en prise) +2.5 (nonQi)
1b. d5xe6  +0
1c. g2xh3  +0

After 1a. Blacks response captures are
1d. ... b4xN +1.5 (nonQi)
1e. ... e6xd5 +0
1f. ... h3xg2 +0
1g. ... BxB   +0

And it is clear that unless the N moves from c3 black will always have an advantageous capture killer move to refute 1b, 1c.
After 1d. Whites captures are
2h. b2xc3 +1 (Qi) - no threats to capturing piece (*)
2i. Bxc3  +1 (Qi)
2j. d5xe6 +0 (nonQ)
2k. g2xh3 +0 (nonQ)

But either of 2h, 2j are good enough to prune the rest of this branch.
(*) However, blacks reply 2. ... e6xd5 allows 3. ... QxN
(which is why it is a good idea to explore zero sum swapoffs)
A position is not quiescent if the K is in check or the opponent has any options to capture with immediate material gain. So that any piece threatened by a lower value piece or pawn also makes it non-quiescent. Sometimes pawn captures can generate a discovered check so it is usually worth exploring (some of) them but that is a matter of taste.
A simpler option is to consider the swapoff value on the each square. IOW are there ay weak spots where player to move can win material just by swapping off pawns and pieces in increasing order of value.
If you have a killer move(s) per ply table it is almost always worth trying it before doing move generation (especially if it is a legal capture).
I expect someone who is more current will be along shortly to correct any mistakes in my analysis but this should give you enough to test your code. The objective is accurate evaluation for the least possible effort.
